# Do-while loops while bound to a socket

Tags: php, sockets

So I've got my PHP script to bind to a socket and write incoming data to a text file, as new information comes down the stream.  This is working well.  What I'd like to do is have another, separate PHP script run each time that text file is updated.

I've tried to make this happen by using an 'include' command, but it's not working.  I've tested that my 'include' method works by mocking up a very simple script with that command.  Maybe I'm putting the line of code in the wrong place?  I have it in the do-while loop (see code below).

Maybe the script/socket needs to be restarted or reset for my changes to take place?

Any help would be appreciated.  Thank you!

Here's the gist of my code:

```
[socket create, bind, and listen stuff goes here]

do {
$input = socket_read($spawn, 4096, 1) or die("Could not read input\n");
$trimmed = trim($input);


if ($trimmed != "") {
  echo date($dateformat) . ": Received input: $trimmed\n";
  if ($trimmed == "END") {
     socket_close($spawn);
     break;
  }
  else {
     // write content
     $fhp = fopen($textFile, 'w') or die("can't open file");
     fwrite($fhp, $trimmed);
     fclose($fhp);
     echo date($date) . ": Wrote: " . $trimmed ."\n";

    // run my other PHP script - the crux of my issue - this is not working
    include '/home/public_html/update.php';

     }
     echo date($dateformat) . ": updated \n";
    }
   }
} while (true);

socket_close($socket);
echo "Socket term\n";
```

Comment: try with - require '/home/public_html/update.php'

Comment: I have figured a couple of things out, but what I really would like to know is:  where should I put that "include" line?  You can see where it is now...it's calling my update.php script, but not at the right time.  I need it to call that script after $textFile has been written to, and it gets written to each time new information is transmitted over the rds/socket.

Comment: Your code contains an unmatched brace.

Answer (score 0):

the logic in the script in your question is

- Start Loop
- Read Socket
- Open File Handle
- Write To file
- Close File
  require '/home/public_html/update.php';
- echo
- Close Socket
- End Loop

i can't understand why the script doesn't work as the way you say because the file gets written and closed before the include() line.
the following line of code is outside of if/else, and might cause some confusion since if the IF condition is TRUE then it will still output that's updated..

```
 echo date($dateformat) . ": updated \n";
```

if problem continues can you paste the update.php script, maybe the problem is located there.

---

--  Edited 
to include the update.php IF the file has content apply this code after the close of the file.

```
if(filesize($textFile) != 0){
 include '/home/public_html/update.php';
}
```

the code above checks if $textFile doesn't equal to zero, in order to include the update.php file.

Comment: Thanks for confirming the logic for me, that is very helpful.  The update.php script works, I can verify that by running it from my browser - it reads the text file and parses it to my database.  When it's called from the script that I've pasted, it passes empty fields to my database...no content from the text file.  I've moved the include line to just above socket_close($socket), to see if that helps.  I'll keep you posted.  Thanks again.

Comment: updated my answer, you might want to check filesize to see if there are any content into the file.

Comment: Hmm, this still isn't working.  It seems to be triggering my update.php file a few times in a row, and not actually returning any data.  I know that recent.php works, and what it does is json_decode the contents of the text file.  But for some reason when it's run from within this script, it runs three times and returns no content.  I'm stumped!